# Regular expression to match string without repeated characters

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a simple regular expression to match the string where no repeated characters.
Example:

- **JHMCU26809C211501** - good
- **JHMGD18508S219366** - good
- JHMCU268091111111 - bad
- **12345678901234567** - good
- ASD1111111ASD2313 - bad
- ASDIIIIIIIASDASD2 - bad
- IIIIIIIADS1EE2345 - bad

Comment: Why do you want this as a regex instead of just coding it out?

Comment: There are restrictions in app :(

Comment: negate this `(\w)\1{3,}`

Comment: I can`t negative regex match. App validator accept only positive matching.

Comment: What do you mean by no repeated characters? Did you mean no repeating letters, because `JHMCU26809C211501` repeats `1`? And if yes - then what is wrong with `JHMCU268091111111`?

Comment: None of your outcomes match the stated problem. Why is that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You may do negation through negative lookahead.

```
^(?!.*(\w)\1{3,}).+$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rK5vZ0/1)

Comment: If it is three times or more, it would be ^(?!.*(\w)\1{2,}).+$

Answer (score 0):

If its a duplicate 3 or more times in a row, this is the fastest
way to do it.  (*no phony demo provided*)

`^(?:(.)(?!\1{2}))+$`

```
 ^ 
 (?:
      ( . )                         # (1)
      (?! \1{2} )
 )+
 $
```