# Python re match two consecutive substrings in logical OR form

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to write a single regex which matches strings

```
"A","B","AB"
```

and which does not match

```
"","AA","BB","BA"
```

I tried a simple pattern

```
re.search(r'^(A)?(B)?',sample_str)
```

But this pattern matches `""`.
I know many solutions which can match this by performing logical operations on multiple patterns but is it possible to match using a single pattern?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I can't figure out the pattern, for ex: why "AB" is OK while "BA" is not. Is it like you construct a language out of "A" and "B" in order?

Comment: if it only accepts these values, why don't you just compare with values ?

Comment: You can just `re.search(r'A|B|AB', sample_str)`, but if you want to find substrings matching that the problem is kind of ill-posed, giving `"AB"` could be interpreted as two matches, `A` and `B`, or one match `AB`.

Comment: @Curcuma_ I cannot compare the values because A and B are two blocks of strings that include other characters. I was trying to generalize the question.

Comment: Please don't generalize it to the point the question doesn't make sense.  Give a complete example of what pattern you would like to match.

Comment: @jdehesa Consider `A` and 'B' themselves as big blocks of strings. I was trying to avoid using multiple logical operations.

Comment: Try `re.search(r'^(?!$)(A)?(B)?$',sample_str)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. Modified some regex from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31897806/regular-expression-to-match-string-without-repeated-characters)

```
regex statement = ^((?=A)A(B?)|(?=B)B)(?!.*(\w)\1)$
```

__

```
d = ['A', 'B', 'AB', '', 'AA', 'BB', 'BA']
for n in d:
     t = re.search('^((?=A)A(B?)|(?=B)B)(?!.*(\w)\1)$', n)
     print(t)

<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='A'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='B'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 2), match='AB'>
None
None
None
None
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems `the anchor`(`^`) needs to be removed like this,

```
(A)?(B)?
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/147)

If you want match `A` or `B` or `AB`, then recommend you try to use the expression, `AB|A|B` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/157)

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that the problem with the current solution is that it matches empty string. You also mentioned that you do not want to repeat writing `A` and `B`, which is satisfied by current solution.

In that case, you can just exclude empty match by [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), ensuring at least one character match:

```
re.search(r'^(?=.)(A)?(B)?$',sample_str)
```

I also added the end-of-string anchor `$` to ensure that trailing characters are not allowed (your `AA` and `BB` examples).

Check it in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/XLg61Q/1/tests)

Of course, this assumes that whatever regex `A` and `B` would be, they do not match empty string.

(and I just noticed that a similar method has been proposed by Wiktor Stribizew in the comments)